# Why can't I open the report manager on SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, reportmanager

Here is the Report Manager URL 
''http://localhost:80/Reports''
when I open this, I ended up getting a blank page on the browser.

[image: The browser]

I have provided Authentication details as well
but I can access to my reports but not to the report manager!

I have added this URL to IE under administrator control. 
how can I access to the Report Manager on SSRS?

Comment: Have you tried with internet explorer?

Comment: I did but same happened

Comment: May be this can help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/tutorial-how-to-locate-and-start-reporting-services-tools-ssrs

Comment: No @McNets it does not have the information that i'm looking for it has the information about how to access ReportServer (Reports on the server) .. i can access the reports but not the Report Manager Web Portal..

Comment: try with http://localhost/reportsserver  I don't remember if one or to ss, http://localhost/reportserver

Comment: I tried it but did not help.